# When I run this code, it just freezes while the audio plays. However, I want an animation to run simultaneously with the audio. How can I do this?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, audio

I have been trying to animate a character using Java Swing Graphics. I transition from the main screen to a JPanel that is supposed to display an animation simultaneously while audio (WAV file) runs. However, the audio runs first, and then the JPanel is shown & animated instead.

How can I fix this error in my code so that both audio and animation function simultaneously?

I know there is an error with my Thread.sleep() function that forces the entire thread to sleep. But, I cannot figure out how to run my audio without the Thread.sleep(), and the threads will not run simultaneously with the Thread.sleep() method present.

I am currently using Java 8.

Audio Class

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
public class AudioManager
{
    static AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;
    static Clip curClip = null;

    public static void playSound(String fileName)
    {

        System.out.println("Playing Sound");

            new Thread(new Runnable() 
            {

                public void run() 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(fileName));
                        curClip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                        curClip.open(audioInputStream); //Opens Stream
                        curClip.start();

                        Thread.sleep(curClip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000); //Pauses the thread
                        audioInputStream.close();
                        curClip.close();
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).run();

    }
}
```

Animator Class calling the Audio Method

```
        Timer t1 = new Timer(background_Intro_Speed, new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                System.out.println(isShowing());
                if(isShowing())
                {
                    System.out.println(audioOver);
                    if(audioOver && animated.xPosition <= 905)
                        animated.xPosition += 5;
                    else if(animated.xPosition > 905 && audioOver)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Animation Ended");
                        swapPanel();
                    }
                    else if(!audioOver)
                    {
                        new Thread(new Runnable() 
                        {           
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                System.out.println("In Thread");
                                AudioManager.playSound("foo.wav");
                                audioOver = true;
                            }
                        }).run();

                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(curClip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);` - there shouldn't be any need to do this - you want to know when the clip completes, use a `LineListener` instead.  Also `Clip` uses it's own thread to play the audio in, so not really sure you need more threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
}).run();
```

Your Thread is not a Thread. You are just executing the run() method of the Thread.

The code should be:

```
}).start();
```

to start a separate Thread so the code doesn't execute on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. However, MadProgrammer's fix worked.

Comment: @AwesomeGuy, may not have fixed this problem, but is still shows how to properly create a separate Thread. You need to use the start() method to create a Thread.

Comment: @camicker, start() repeatedly calls the thread. I only need it to run once.

Comment: @AwesomeGuy No it doesn't. A Thread can only be started once. If it runs repeatedly, then you are calling the code repeatedly. The point of using a Thread is to have the code execute on a separate Thread. If you use run() then you are just invoking a method, not executing a Thread.